# How method_missing could handle various find_by_*

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, metaprogramming

I am researching with find_by_* in ActiveRecord, it turns out the following code plays the role. If anyone could detail me why the following method works with find_by_* methods?

```
def method_missing(name, *arguments, &block)
      match = Method.match(self, name)

      if match && match.valid?
        match.define
        send(name, *arguments, &block)
      else
        super
      end
end
```

Comment: The implementation of `Method.match` and its `valid?` and `define` methods seem to be important in this context...

Comment: What is the *specific* problem you have with reading and understanding the code? You've found the method_missing code. Have you looked at Method and Method.match and what it returns? And the code for define?